# Changing color of point on chart based on event from third column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a simple line graph based on Google Analytics data tracking the number of users each day. I've added a point on the line graph marking each date. Code looks like this...

```
ggplot(web_visit_vs_email_deployed.df,aes(x = date, y = users))+
 geom_line()+
 geom_point(aes(color = !is.na(Program)))+
 theme_tq() +
 labs(
   title = "Website Visits vs. Emails Deployed",
   x = "",
   y = "Users",
   color = "Email Deployed"
)
```

I'd like to change the color of the points on dates that we deployed a marketing email. I've joined the data frame used to plot the above with the "email date" column from another data frame containing email performance metrics. It resulted in the following table...

```
    date                users Program
    <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>  
  1 2020-01-01 00:00:00    80 NA     
  2 2020-01-02 00:00:00   183 NA     
  3 2020-01-03 00:00:00   176 NA     
  4 2020-01-04 00:00:00    86 NA     
  5 2020-01-05 00:00:00    87 NA     
  6 2020-01-06 00:00:00   164 NA     
  7 2020-01-07 00:00:00   177 NA     
  8 2020-01-08 00:00:00   136 NA     
  9 2020-01-09 00:00:00   515 HEA    
 10 2020-01-10 00:00:00   231 NA     
 # ... with 53 more rows
```

This now creates two separate line graphs based on "Program" column being "NA" or "HEA" in two different colors. Instead I'd like one line with different colored points based on "Program" column being "NA" or "HEA"

Edit: Updated plot and data frame

Edit 2: Did some more playing around and solved it. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: The easy solution would be to plot the email dates on top of the existing plot, by adding this line after line 3 of your original code: `geom_point(aes(x = \`Email Date\`), color = 'red', size = 2) +` which makes larger red points on top of the small black points

Comment: Thanks. It's just giving me a completely blank plot. I believe the issue comes from my data frame having <NA> values in the "Email Date" column where I have "user" values and vice-versa. Once I get that sorted, I like this solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to make a dummy variable column, where 1 means that you did send an email, and 0 means that you did not. That way, the dummy variable column can be used for the color aesthetic.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

web_visit_by_date.df = data.frame('date' = c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03'), 'users' = c(80, 183, 176)) # replicating your data snippet

email_dates = c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-03') # the join didn't make sense to me, so I left this as a list

# making the dummy variable using ifelse. The argument is checking to see if the
# date column contains a value from the email_dates list. If yes, then that row 
# equals true and gets a 1 in the new email column. Otherwise, that row equals
# false and gets a 0 in the new email column. 

web_visit_by_date.df$email =  ifelse((c(web_visit_by_date.df$date %in% email_dates) == TRUE), 1, 0)

# all that's left is to set color = as.factor(email) in the aes argument

ggplot(web_visit_by_date.df,aes(x = date, y = users, color = as.factor(email)))+
 geom_line()+
 geom_point()+
 labs(
 title = "Website Visits vs. Emails Deployed",
 x = "",
 y = "Users"
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this solution will work, but as you alluded to, my join of the two data frames didn't really make sense. I found a way to join them by "date" it's giving me duplicates in the "date" column on days I sent an email with NA values in the "users" column on one instance of each duplicate "date". Close to figuring this out though.

Comment: Figued out data frame join in a way I think works. Edited original post with new outputs for plot and data frame if you're able to help!